# Edit current table value through user input tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

I am not sure if this question has really been answered as I have found similar questions and have tried the solution(s) without the desired result.

I have the following script to run that updates data in an existing table:

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
from tkinter.ttk import *
import sys
from datetime import datetime

root = Tk()
root.geometry('380x250')
root.title("Stock Movement")
root.config(bg="lightskyblue1")
style = Style()

ItemCode = StringVar()
Description = StringVar()
Quantity = IntVar()
var = IntVar()
c = StringVar()
var1 = IntVar()
var2 = IntVar()
dateTimeObj = datetime.now()

timestampStr = dateTimeObj.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")


def database():
    code = ItemCode.get()
    quantity = Quantity.get()
    description = Description.get()

    with sqlite3.connect('Test.sql3') as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()


        # I believe I would need to edit the next line to add a variable, but that messes around with the amount of variables used. I have to try and only add or subtract an integer where a certain Itemcode is found. 
        cursor.execute('UPDATE StockSheet SET Quantity=?, LastRec=? WHERE ItemCode=?', (quantity, timestampStr, code,))


        updated = cursor.rowcount
        cursor.close()
        conn.commit()
        root.destroy()
        sys.exit(updated)  # return value whether record has been updated

# Inserting labels and field of input
label_0 = Label(root, text="Stock Movement", background="lightskyblue1", width=20, font=("Arial", 20, "bold")).place(x=90, y=23)

label_1 = Label(root, text="Item Code", width=20, background="lightskyblue1", font=("Arial", 12, "bold")).place(x=20, y=100)

entry_1 = Entry(root, textvar=ItemCode, background="lightskyblue1", font=("Arial", 12, "bold")).place(x=180, y=100)

label_2 = Label(root, text="Quantity", width=10, background="lightskyblue1", font=("Arial", 12, "bold")).place(x=20, y=140)

entry_2 = Entry(root, textvar=Quantity, background="lightskyblue1", font=("Arial", 12, "bold")).place(x=180, y=140)


# Style of buttons
style.configure('C.TButton', font=('Arial', 12, 'bold'), foreground='red')
style.configure('S.TButton', font=('Arial', 12, 'bold'), foreground='blue')

# Inserting buttons
submit1 = Button(root, text='Submit', style='S.TButton', width=11, command=database).place(x=20, y=190)
exit1 = Button(root, text='Close', style='C.TButton', width=11, command=root.destroy).place(x=260, y=190)

root.mainloop()
```

At the moment it is replacing the current value e.g I have a quantity of 250 in the current database. The user inputs 100. The database displays 100.
I would like to know if it is possible for me the add or subtract this value to give a result showing 350/150 respectively.

I have read through the SQL documentation, but it seems quite vague in this sense.

I previously tried to use the SQL data as an `IntVar` and using it in the code, but to no success.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `Quantity=Quantity+?` in the SQL statement?

Comment: @acw1668 Worked perfectly. I get lost between the collaboration syntax between python and SQL sometimes. I did assume that if the subtraction needs to be done you can just enter a negative number. Also worked. **Thank you** so much. Looks like I would have to acknowledge your help with my final program.

Comment: @acw1668 What could possibly be wrong if it runs the script, but it is not changing the value in the database? No error, just no alteration.

Comment: Try swapping `cursor.close()` and `conn.commit()`.

Comment: @acw1668 Works perfectly !! Thank you. I struggle sometimes because it logically makes sense for the `cursor.close()` to be before `conn.commit()`.